# How to make Zend Form element attributes encode HTML elements using correct encoding?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, escaping

When using `Zend\Form\Element\Select` option that contains HTML entities, how do I encode it correctly?

**Try 1:**

I pass in `90&deg;`, I see it unconverted (same as `90&deg;`) in my HTML select box, instead of the expected degree symbol (`°`)

**Try 2:**

I use ° directly in my label name, I see this: `90�`

**Zend Code**

Chasing the Zend Form code appears to yield these lines:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AbstractHelper.php#L248,

where `$escape` is the `$this->getEscapeHtmlHelper()` method.

and actual conversion happens here:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-escaper/blob/master/src/Escaper.php#L369

Comment: I saved my file using `UTF-8` encoding and it shows okay now

Answer (score 0):

Re-saving the source file that contained the degree symbol directly (°) using `UTF-8` encoding seems to have done the job.

(Before it was encoded using ANSI)

Incidentally that degree symbol now shows up like this in my IDE:  `Â°`